# Strange substitution in HMC

Tags: probability, bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, hamiltonian-monte-carlo

I try to read paper, [MCMC using Hamiltonian dynamics](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1206.1901.pdf)). The author, Neal states(P28):

> To begin, Cruetz nodes that the following relationship holds when any Metropolis-style algorithm is used to sample a density $P(x) = (1/Z)\exp(-E(x))$:
>
> $$
> 1 = \mathbb{E}(P(x^*)/P(x)) = \mathbb{E}(\exp(-(E(x^*)-E(x)))) = \mathbb{E}(\exp(-\Delta)) \quad (4.17)
> $$

I can't see why $\mathbb{E}(P(x^*)/P(x))=1$ so I follow the reference, 
[Global Monte Carlo algorithms for many-fermion systems](https://quark.phy.bnl.gov/~creutz/mypubs/pub100.pdf), and found this strange substitution(P3):

> Some rather useful identities follow from considering expectation values over this distributions. Consider the paritition function
>
> $$
> Z = \int dA' dp' e^{-H'} = \int dAdp e^{-H}e^{H-H'}, \quad (16)
> $$
>
> where $H$ and $H'$ denote $H(p,A)$ and $H(p',A')$, respectively.

I can't see why it is valid. $A = A', p = p'$ may works but it will imply $\mathbb{E}(P(x^*)/P(x))=\mathbb{E}(1)=1$? It sounds not the point Neal want to present.

Comment: Are you using E both to denote expectation and the energy?

Comment: Yes, I have fixed the latex code.

Comment: If not exactly a duplicate, quite correlated with this [question of a few weeks ago.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/423739/7224)

Answer (score 1):

If $K$ is a Markov kernel(with density $k$) with stationary distribution $P$ (with density $p$), then, if $(X_t)_t$ is a stationary Markov chain associated with $K$,
\begin{align*}\mathbb E\left[\frac{p(X_{t+1})}{p(X_t)}\right] &=\int_{\mathfrak{X^2}} \frac{p(x_{t+1})}{p(x_t)} p(x_t)k(x_t,x_{t+1})\text{d}\lambda(x_t)\text{d}\lambda(x_{t+1}) \\
&= \int_{\mathfrak{X^2}} p(x_{t+1}) k(x_t,x_{t+1})\text{d}\lambda(x_t)\text{d}\lambda(x_{t+1})\\
\end{align*}
Unless $k$ is symmetric and with a support at least equal to $\mathfrak X$, the support of $p$, there is no reason for the ratio to be of expectation one.